# Will objects be copied in assignment in D?

Tags: reference, d, ownership, copy-assignment

When I assign an object in D, will it be copied?

```
void main() {
    auto test = new Test(new Object());
    tset.obj;
}

class Test {
    public Object obj;

    public this(Object ref origObj) {
        obj = origObj; // Will this copy origObj into obj, or will origObj and obj point to the same data? (Is this a valid way to pass ownership without copying the object?)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only the reference is copied, the object itself isn't duplicated. You can explicitly duplicate the object by using `.dup` though.

Comment: You would have to declare a `dup` method for whatever class you were trying to `dup` first, just like you would have to define a `clone` method in Java or C#. There is no built-in way to dup/clone/copy a class in D.

Answer (score 3):

Classes are reference types, so when you have

```
Object o;
```

`o` is a reference to an `Object` rather than an actual `Object`, so copying it just copies the reference. It's just like with pointers.

```
auto a = new int;
*a = 5;

auto b = a;
assert(a is b);
assert(*a == *b);

*b = 5;
assert(*a == 5);
```

I would advise reading either [The D Programming Language](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0321635361) by Andrei Alexandrescu, or Ali Çehreli's [D Programming Language Tutorial](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/index.html). In particular, [this chapter](http://ddili.org/ders/d.en/class.html) of Ali's book discusses classes, including how to assign and copy them.